# File not found in sceneform 1.16

Tags: java, arcore, sceneform, android-studio-4.0

My app is not able to read/load the file from local. I am using Android Studio 4.0 and Sceneform 1.16. The code works fine if I use https path (Ex. https://storage.googleapis.com/ar-answers-in-search-models/static/Tiger/model.glb)

The problem is 'File not found' error. In the below code i have also use getApplicationContext()  instead of 'this'. Problematic part

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this,Uri.parse("/sampledata/models/abc.glb")  )    <--- Problem
                    .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(......
```

Have added below permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the image through

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this,R.raw.abc)
```

But I am not getting the texture or material. I am exporting the image/object from blender.
Also, would like to know if uri.parse("") can work with object saved locally. The above way has its own limitations.

Not marking this as solved for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your glb in `asset` directory.

And load it like below

`ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("model.glb"))`

Or if your glb is saved in device storage,

`ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.fromFile(File(YOUR_GLB_PATH)))`

Comment: Both of them didn't seems to work. I assume its problem with sceneform 1.16.  The error I get is E/ModelRenderable: Unable to load Renderable registryId='file:///assets/abc.glb'
    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/abc.glb (No such file or directory)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.SceneformBufferUtils.inputStreamToByteBuffer(SceneformBufferUtils.java:108)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:118). Thx

Comment: Double check if the glb file is in your asset directory.

Let's say your glb filename is "model.glb", then you use this as parameter to Uri,parse() like,

        ModelRenderable
            .builder()
            .setSource(context, Uri.parse("model.glb"))
            .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
            .build()
            .thenAccept {
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can access a GLB model from assets as follows - the below example is Kotlin and is tested againstmSceneform 1.18 which is the same as Sceneform 1.16.

```js
        //Build the renderable - this uses the new to Sceneform 1.16 glb model format
        val modelFilePath =  getFileFromAssets(this, "yourModel.glb").absolutePath
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(
                        this,
                        Uri.parse(
                                modelFilePath))
                .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(
                        Consumer { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
                            //Add anything you want to do here....
                            Log.d(TAG,"Model loaded")
                        })
                .exceptionally( Function<Throwable, Void?> { throwable: Throwable? ->
                            //Add anything you want to do here e.g.:
                            Log.d(TAG, "ModelRenderable.builder exception: " + throwable)
                            null
                        })
```